# Activating MySites problem

Tags: my-site, forms-authentication

We have FBA on SP2010.

​This is for Activating My Sites - But I have understood that does not happen without user profile services. We have activated it in Site features but in central admin it has to be associated to a user mgmt application in Active Directory (AD). 
However, there is no option to associate it with FBA.

So, My question: Is it possible to create/install a user profile services which works with FBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot OOB synchronize with a membership provider.

There are options, but no easy ones i am afraid.

One option is to extract an LDIF file and synchronize against itn (see info on TechNet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff959234.aspx)).

Another option is to manually add the users from your membership provider using the object model, and create a timer job that does the full/incremental sync. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx) is a sample for working with the UserProfileManager.